# CORS error for the html content with CDN for Magento2 website

Tags: nginx, cors, magento2, cdn

I am configuring the StackPath CDN for my Magento2 website. Server used is Nginx for running the Magento2 website.

I am using following tutorial https://absolutecommerce.co.uk/blog/cors-in-magento-2

My CORS config file has following data

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' 'always';

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' 'always';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, GET, OPTIONS HEAD' always;
    #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'x-requested-with' 'always';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Cache-Hash' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400 'always';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0 'always';
    return 204;
}
```

My host configuration

```
## Example configuration:
upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
     #server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
 }

 server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www.example.com.pem;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    if ($http_user_agent ~ (bingbot) ) {
       return 503;
   }
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version[^/]+/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;  ### cors config file ###
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;  ### cors config file ###
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf; ### cors config file ###

    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200;
        }

}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=2G \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    application/font-woff
    image/jpeg
    image/png    
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
}
```

media, js, css and fonts are loading properly but I am getting following CORS error for the **html** content.
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks ok. But You nevertheless on preflight options request getting 405 - method not allowed. Instead of 204.
Are You absolutely sure that in location catching html files you also have included this CORS config?

Comment: I have added more details to question, please check.

Comment: I'm not familiar with magento, so i'm not sure where your html files came from. But You have to add your cors include block in location responsible for those files. 
Possibly just below:
location / {